# Start a service (or services) with a double-click without the UAC prompt

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, uac

I'd like to put an icon on my taskbar (pinned), quick launch toolbar ([how to add a QLT on Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/add-the-quick-launch-bar-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/)) or system tray, that if I click or double-click it, it will restart a preset Windows service without the UAC prompt.

Of course this may mean there's already a certain elevated app running and my click simply tells this app to start the service.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**How to Create a Elevated Program Shortcut without a UAC Prompt**](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html)

> create a elevated "[Run as administrator](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html)" shortcut of any installed program in Windows using Task Scheduler so that it will not give you a UAC prompt for permission when you start it while still having [UAC](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/299-user-account-control-uac-change-notification-settings.html) turned on.
>
> You can run at startup as a task, Pin to Start Menu, **[Pin to Taskbar](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/397-taskbar-pin-unpin-program-links.html)**, assign a keyboard shortcut to the shortcut created below, or move to where you like for easy use.

which takes you to,

> The pinned taskbar items are located in this [hidden](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/394-hidden-files-folders-show-hide.html) system folder:

```
C:\Users\(User-Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

**Procedure** (the title link above has a more detailed version with pictures and an example),

1. Run **taskschd.msc**
2. Select `Task Scheduler Library` in the left pane,
   click on `Create task` in the far right pane
3. Type name of the program in the `General` tab (shortcut name)
4. Check the `Run with highest privileges` box
5. Click on the `Configure for` drop down box to open it,
   and select `Windows® 7, Windows Server™ 2008 R2`
6. Click on the `Actions` tab, then on the New button
7. Under '"Action"', select 'Start a program' and click on the 'Browse' button
8. Navigate to the `.exe` file of the program that you want to create this shortcut for,
   then select it and click on `Open`
9. Click on `OK`
10. There is an additional step for laptops to avoid stopping it when on battery
11. You will now see your new task created with the name you gave it in step 3
12. Close `Task Schedular`
13. Right click on a empty area of the desktop, then click on `New` and `Shortcut`
14. Type in `schtasks /run /tn task-name` for the location, then click on the `Next` button
15. You can now change its icon and [pin it to taskbar](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/397-taskbar-pin-unpin-program-links.html)