# Start service from Task Scheduler as minimised

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

After creating a scheduled task after following [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/299451), I can successfully start a service without the UAC prompt. The options selected were:

- `Start a program`
- `Program\script` = `C:\Windows\System32\net.exe`
- `Add arguments (optional)` = `start "SERVICE-NAME"`

Then in a batch file I call `schtasks /run /tn TASK-NAME`. After testing this, I created a shortcut to the batch file and set the `Run` option  to `Minimised`.

This all works except that when the actual service is started, a maximised command prompt window pops up with the single line `The SERVICE-NAME service is starting`. This then disappears after a few seconds.

How do I tell Task Scheduler to start the target program silently (or minimised) without the pop-up? If the pop-up command prompt were minimised that would be fine.

Comment: On the scheduled task, be sure the option `Run whether user is logged on or not` is selected as well which I didn't see mentioned in the linked post... check here for common troubleshooting guidance as well: https://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you configure the shortcut to run minimized you launch minimized only the program that starts the scheduled task, not the program that the task executes. You need another piece in your Rube Goldberg machine launch sequence, make the following changes:

- `Program\script` = `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
- `Add arguments (optional)` = `/c start /min net start "SERVICE-NAME"`

The first "start" is the `cmd.exe` `start` command, which we use for two functions:

1. Launch `net.exe` minimized.
2. Make `taskeng.exe` finish as soon as `net.exe` is launched instead of waiting for it to finish.

Note that this solution is not perfect as `taskeng.exe` will flash briefly until the `net.exe` is launched, but usually less than a second.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I briefly tried to use `start` but couldn't get the syntax right. This works perfectly. There is a brief flash as the action (`net start SERVICE-NAME`) is launched, but very short.

Comment: Yes, `taskeng.exe` is what you say.

Comment: You need to add `""` after the first START, or it will misparse any quoted argument as a window title, and give an error 'The system cannot find the file' for the next argument. Use `/c start "" /min net start "SERVICE-NAME"`.

Comment: @stevek_mcc I tested it before posting the answer and worked fine without adding the extra quotes.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez Ah, I see the difference - thanks: my command wasn't `start /min net start "..."` but `start /min "c:\Program Files\..."` - START mis-parses if the first argument after the /options has quotes, but parses OK for quotes later.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a service (or any other program) without any window flashing at all, **not even minimized**.

Create a task:

- Command/script: `mshta.exe`
- Add arguments (optional) :
  `"javascript: new ActiveXObject('shell.application').ShellExecute('net.exe', 'start <SERVICE-NAME>', '', 'open', 0); close();"`

Since you want to start a service, you need administrative rights, so check *Run with highest privileges* at the first tab.

To run the task without showing any window, you use the same trick. Create a shortcut with the following command:

```
mshta.exe "javascript: new ActiveXObject('shell.application').ShellExecute('schtasks.exe', '/run /tn <TASK-NAME>', '', 'open', 0); close();"
```

### Notes

- The user that runs the shortcut must be an admin because normal users
  can run only their tasks and this task is one with highest
  privileges. Otherwise, the `schtasks` command will fail with "access is denied".
- If the task is in a task folder, the `/tn <TASK-NAME>` is `/tn <FOLDER>\<TASK>` from the shell, and you must **double the
  backslash** to escape it in the `mshta` command of the shortcut.
- Some antivirus programs (at least Kaspersky) may consider a task
  using `mshta` this way as suspicious or a potential risk, and thus
  delete it.
- You can use this trick to run any program hidden without popping up whatsoever. Just replace `net.exe` with the name of your program and the `start <SERVICE-NAME>` part with the needed parameters.

Comment: I prefer that one, it briefly takes away the focus like the flashing .cmd version, but there is no window flashing up and no minimized task visible. Try with `mshta "javascript: new ActiveXObject('shell.application').ShellExecute('ping.exe', '-n 10 127.0.0.1', '', 'open', 0); close();"` and you will see ping for ten second only in the task manager.

Comment: That even works on Windows XP and Windows 2000! Just tested out of curiosity...

Answer (score 0):

[Start Program Minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTEGa.png)

Only this works for me, Windows 11

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).